# Shortcut to Close Intellij File Tab

Tags: intellij-idea

I love intellij's file tab but I can't seem to find a way to shortcut closing a tab similar to the behavior of `ctrl + w` in chrome. I can't find the option in the keymap editor. Am I missing something or is this not implemented?

I found this [page](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/closing-files-in-the-editor.html) but it doesn't include the action name. I would use `ctrl + f4` but my window manager has that reserved and I would rather change it.

Answer (score 90, accepted):

1. Open `Settings` by hitting `Ctrl+Alt+S`
2. Click: `Keymap`
3. Search for: `Close`
4. Under `Main menu > Window > Editor Tabs`, find `Close`.
5. Right-click and click `Remove Ctrl+F4`.
6. Right click and click `Add Keyboard Shortcut`
7. Add your new custom Keyboard Shortcut.

IntelliJ will tell you if the shortcut clashes with another shortcut performing a different action.

---

Alternatively, open/edit your Linux Window Manager Settings and remove the `Ctrl+F4` mapping to allow other programs like IntelliJ to make use of it.

Comment: On Ubuntu KDE Neon, this shortcut didn't work because it was already in use by the KDE with the function: "Switch to Desktop 4". I disabled this shortcut in the Settings -> Workspace -> Shortcuts -> Global Shortcuts -> KWin -> Switch to Desktop 4.

Comment: More in line with what you're looking for, OP, after step 5, also remove the existing Ctrl+W shortcut (`Window > Active Tool Window > Close Active Tab`), and remap the `Editor Tabs > Close` shortcut to Ctrl+W

Answer (score 18):

For PC-based keyboards, the shortcut to close tabs is <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>F4</kbd>,
*not* to be confused with <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>F4</kbd>.

Comment: My window manager on linux already has a mapping for that. Do you know what the action that corresponds to is? I found this page but it doesn't say what the action is: https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/closing-files-in-the-editor.html

Comment: @inquisitiveIdiot: It'd be the "Close" action.

Comment: If you use open Settings (`Ctrl+Alt+S`), then go to "Keymap". Search for "Close" and then add another shortcut (eg. `Ctrl+#`).

Answer (score 8):

Current tab can be closed with:

> Ctrl + F4

Works on Intellij Ultimate 2016.3

Answer (score 5):

On mac OS, Intellij 2018.3 version, 'Command + W' does close the file tab. [image]

Answer (score 0):

---

As we can see in the image [in this discussion](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/206411479/comments/115000370190):

Go in Settings >> Keymap >> Main menu >> Other >> [Close Active Editor] and change to Ctrl+W.

Answer (score 0):

I'm on version 2020.1 and this has changed to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>4</kbd>